# Is the axiom of choice needed to show that countable cartesian product has countable base?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $(\Omega_n,\mathcal T_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a a sequence of topological spaces with countable base. For $n\geq1$, let $\{V^k_n:k\in I_n\}$ be a countable base of $(\Omega_n,\mathcal T_n)_{n\geq1}$, where $I_n$ is finite or countably infinite. Let $\Omega:=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\Omega_n$ and let $\mathcal T$ be the product topology on $\Omega$. For all $p\geq 1$ let

$$\mathcal{H}^p:=\bigg\{V_1^{k_1}\times\dots\times V_p^{k_p}\times\prod_{n=p+1}^\infty\Omega_n : (k_1,\dots, k_p)\in I_1\times\dots\times I_p\bigg\}$$

and let $\mathcal{H}:=\cup_{p\geq1}\mathcal{H}^p$. The goal is to show that $\mathcal{H}$ is a countable base for $(\Omega,\mathcal T)$. Suppose we have already shown that $\mathcal{H}$ is countable. Consider the following argument:

Let $U\in \mathcal T$ and let $x\in U$. By definition of the product topology there exist $p\geq 1$ and open sets $U_1,\dots, U_p$ in $\Omega_1,\dots,\Omega_p$ respectively such that

$$ x\in  U_1\times\dots\times U_p\times\prod_{n=p+1}^\infty\Omega_n \subset U$$

Now, for each $1\leq n\leq p$, there exist $I'_n\subset I_n$ such that $U_n=\cup_{k\in I'_n}V^k_n$. In particular there exist $k_n\in I'_n\subset I_n$ such that $x_n \in V^k_n$. We have found $k_1,\dots,k_p$ such that

$$x \in V_x:= V_1^{k_1}\times\dots\times V_p^{k_p} \times\prod_{n=p+1}^\infty\Omega_n$$

Since $V_x \in \mathcal{H}^p\subset \mathcal{H}$, $U=\cup_{x\in U} V_x$ and $U$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $\mathcal{H}$ is a countable base for $(\Omega,\mathcal T)$.

**Question:** Is the axiom of choice used here? I feel it is used twice: first at the beginning to pick a countable base for each topology and then also to pick $V_x$ for each $x$. Is this correct? Is there a way to avoid using the axiom of choice?

Comment: You're also using choice when saying a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma True so that would be three times?

Comment: Well, once you have $V_n^k$ (by choice) you can structure your proof to not needing to appeal to choice to get $\mathcal{H}$ countable.  So only twice (actually can reduce it down to once if you pick $V_x$ more carefully).

Comment: You don't use choice in the last part: $x \in U$ open, then for some $B$ in the base $x \in B \subseteq U$ only requires finitely many choices.

Comment: If you consider the bases of $X_n$ to be pre-given and pre-indexed by $\Bbb N$, you don't need any choice  at all.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Could you expand on that? How can you choose $V_x$ for each $x$ without choice?

Comment: $\mathcal{B}$ is a base iff for all  open $O$ and all $x \in O$ there is some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ so that $x \in B \subseteq O$. So we only need to show how this  can be done for some $O$ and some $x \in O$. No choice needed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I was using the definition $\mathcal{B}$ is a base iff all open sets are unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. I thought we needed the axiom of choice to show the equivalence between the two definitions. But it seems like we don't: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3059216/522332.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma And what about the countability of $\mathcal{H}$. How can you do it without choice?

Comment: Use an explicit bijection between $\omega^{<\omega}$ and $\omega$ and assume the bijection between $\omega$ and the countable base $\mathcal{B}_n$ of $X_n$ is pre-given.